# How to make sass map-get return full combined expression

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, scss-mixins

I have an scss object like this

```
$device-media-queries: (
  mobile: (max-width: 639px),
  tablet: (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 640px),
  desktop: (min-width: 1025px)
);
```

that I am using `map-get` on in a mixin like

```
$target-device-media-query: map-get($device-media-queries, $device-description);
```

However, in the case of `$device-description` being `tablet`, `$target-device-media-query` only becomes the last item in the clause, which in this case is `(min-width: 640px)`.

How do I make `$target-device-media-query` equal to both the expressions, so: `(max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 640px)` so that my media query doesn't get screwed up and tablet styles wouldn't also be apply to a desktop device (due to `(min-width: 640px)` applying)? When I do the combined media query directly without using a mixin, things work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `(` and `)` are sass map delimiters. You should use quotation marks around each media-query:

```
$device-media-queries: (
  mobile: '(max-width: 639px)',
  tablet: '(max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 640px)',
  desktop: '(min-width: 1025px)'
);

@media #{map-get($device-media-queries, tablet)} { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use double-quotes as below :

```
$device-media-queries: (
  mobile: "(max-width: 639px)",
  tablet: "(max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 640px)",
  desktop: "(min-width: 1025px)"
);

$target-device-media-query: map-get($device-media-queries, tablet);

@media #{$target-device-media-query} {
  .element:before {
    content: $target-device-media-query;
  }
}
```